# SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'ftp_exchange' already exists. Cannot update my repository

Tags: mysql, database, sql-update, data-migration, sequelpro

```
 (
                `id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                `type` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                `local_root_directory` VARCHAR(255),
                `local_directory` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                `remote_host` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                `remote_port` INTEGER DEFAULT 21 NOT NULL,
                `is_ssl` TINYINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
                `is_sftp` TINYINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
                `is_passive` TINYINT DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL,
                `timeout` INTEGER DEFAULT 30 NOT NULL,
                `username` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                `password` VARCHAR(255),
                `private_key` VARCHAR(255),
                `remote_directory` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                `is_recursive` TINYINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
                `is_delete_after_success` TINYINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
                `is_overwrite_existing` TINYINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
                `filename_pattern` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '.*' NOT NULL,
                `is_active` TINYINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
                `weekday` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '*' NOT NULL,
                `year` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '*' NOT NULL,
                `month` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '*' NOT NULL,
                `day` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '*' NOT NULL,
                `hour` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '*' NOT NULL,
                `minute` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '*' NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
                UNIQUE INDEX `name_unique` (`name`)
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB". Aborting migration.
```

**Problem**

It gives an error after I importet a new table from a database dump. Could it be, that I importet the database twice. And if yes, how can fix this in my local repository? Thank you :-)

Comment: If you're importing and some tables already exist maybe you need to clear the database it out before importing. **Remember to make backups before doing anything that might result in data loss**.

Comment: Thank you. How can I clear the duplicate database above?

Comment: `DROP DATABASE` or equivalent. Remember this won't ask for confirmation, it just does it. **DO NOT AIM AT ANYTHING IMPORTANT**.